# How to calculate ratio for every row in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, sum, visualization, calculated-columns

Could someone please guide me through this situation?

I have a need to compute for every row the ratio between, volume of the row and sum of volumes of rows of a given transport type.

But after calculating this calculated column, I would like to use it in a table visualization, and be affected by any slicer of it...

Was I clear?

Here follows the example of rows:

```
 Delivery Method Order Nr VOLUME Ratio
Air              50102258      9 33%
Sea              50091716     50 52%
Sea              50092425     47 48%
Air              50102257     18 67%
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your measure (a calculated column doesn't work here since you have to aggregate per method):

```
% Volume = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('Table'[VOLUME]),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[VOLUME]),
        ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Delivery Method])
    )
)
```

[image]

If the answer was useful please accept it and give it an upvote.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Peter. Althought I can't come with the desired output, since the table has dates associated with deliveries, when I use the slicer in the visualization page, the table gives me the ratios based on totals for every record the table has, and not for the time period we are seeing...
Is there a way around this?